# Materialize - Like that triggers sidenav disappears

Tags: css, materialize

I am trying to get a sidemenu to work on Materialize when should be very simple:

First I add the sidenav content to the page:

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
<li><div class="user-view">
  <div class="background">
    <img src="images/office.jpg">
  </div>
  <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
  <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
</div></li>
<li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
<li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
<li><div class="divider"></div></li>
<li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
<li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I add the jquery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});
```

And finally the part where to problem is:

I have a nav which goes at the top of the page:

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="brand-logo" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><img src="icon.png" alt="" /></a>

  <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down" style="position: relative; left: 100px;">
    <li><a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger">Trigger SideNav</a></li><!-- This is just not showing -->
  </ul>

</div>
</nav>
```

For some reason this menu is not showing:

```
 <li><a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger">Trigger SideNav</a></li>
```

unless I take this off it ... `data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I know this is not a problem and the element that has sidenav-trigger class will be shown when the width of the browser is less than 993px. just resize your browser window width to reach less than 993px and see the result.

If it does not work:

I think the problem can be with the content of your link. replace the image with a text and try again.

Comment: I need to link to appear at all times at any size but it just doesn't appear at all at any size unless I remove the parts that trigger the sidenav

Comment: just remove the class sidenav-trigger and it will be ok. not the data-target

Comment: OK, I've taken out the class "sidenav-trigger" and like you said, the link appeared! Only issue now is the when I click on it the sideNav doesn't come out. I'm I forgetting something?

Comment: the id of sidenav content and data-target must be exactly the same. and to initialize sidenav using jquery make sure you are importing the jquery.js before materialize.js

Comment: It's all correct and the jquery part is: $('.sidenav').sidenav();   I don't get why its not showing

Comment: use the js version instead maybe it works! before doing this see the console of developer tools. do you see any error? what about using js version?

Comment: Used: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
  }); but still no sidenav  ... also, no errors at all

Comment: where are you putting the code? it should be after loading jquery and materialize js files

Comment: Yes, thats where I'm putting it

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Moein said (the `sidenav-trigger` menu only appears when the page width is less than 993px), you can make it appear all the same adding the `show-on-large` class to your menu button.

Something like:

```
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#" data-target="slide-out">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reputation reasons, I'm not allowed to comment. It'll work with the javascript code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, {});
});
```

Instead of the code which is given in the official documentation you've to change this piece of code

```
M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
```

with this

```
M.Sidenav.init(elems, {});
```

With the official javascript code you'll notice that there's an error in the console when you load the page.